# Can't get response from socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am studying about sockets in java. I created a simple tcp client which is aimed to send an HTTP request and receive the response. But after running the client it just waits and there is no response. Here is my code:

```
public static void connect(){
    try (
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
        PrintWriter writer 
            = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader 
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        socket.setSoTimeout(60000);
        String request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
            "Host: localhost\r\n" +
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n";
        writer.write(request);
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        System.out.println("Response: ");
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Response: 
Read timed out
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 0 seconds)
```

NOTE:
I know I can use more abstracted classes in java like `url` classes, etc for this purpose. As I said I am studying about sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To terminate the request section of an HTTP request, you need to send **two** newlines, not just one.

```
String request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: localhost\r\n" +
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n\r\n";
```

Notice the double **`\r\n\r\n`** at the end of the string.

If you don't terminate the request, the HTTP server at the other end will just sit there waiting for you to terminate the request, and your code will wait for an answer that will never come.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin for your response, But I also tried the carriage return line feed sequence and nothing changes. I think there might be a problem in the way I send request and read the response.

Comment: The problem is exactly @Erwin has stated. Have you really tried a blank line at the end of the request headers as stated here?

Comment: Thank you @EJP and Erwin I forgot that